# I cant insert multiple photos together with multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I cant insert multiple photos together with multiple rows.

I have here input fields:

```
<input name="u_code[]" required="required" style="margin:0px; ">
<input name="u_name[]" required="required" style="margin:0px; ">
<input name="u_address[]" required="required" style="margin:0px; ">
<input name="photo[]" required="required" style="margin:0px; ">
```

and this is my controller:

```
function user_add()
{
if ($_POST) 
{
    $u_id =$this->input->post('u_id');
    $u_code =$this->input->post('u_code');
    $u_name =$this->input->post('u_name');
    $u_address = $this->input->post('u_address');

    $data = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('u_id')); $i++)
    {

        $data[$i] = array(
            'u_id' => $u_id[$i],
            'u_code' => $u_code[$i],
            'u_name' => $u_name[$i],
            'u_address' => $u_address[$i],

        );
    }
        $insert = $this->user_model->user_add($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
}
```

My problem is i dont know where what exact code should be add to upload photos in a multiple rows.

please check photo here:
[screenshot of input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI46B.jpg)
Thanks advance for the help..

Comment: you can use foreach loop for the _FILES['fupload']['name'].

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function user_add()
{
    if ($_POST) {
        $u_id = $this->input->post('u_id');
        $u_code = $this->input->post('u_code');
        $u_name = $this->input->post('u_name');
        $u_address = $this->input->post('u_address');

        $data = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('u_id')); $i++) {

            $data[$i] = array(
                'u_id' => $u_id[$i],
                'u_code' => $u_code[$i],
                'u_name' => $u_name[$i],
                'u_address' => $u_address[$i],

                );
            $insert = $this->user_model->user_add($data);
        }        
        echo json_encode(array("status" => true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code may this help in understanding you how to handle multiple images

```
$files = $_FILES;
$count = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
    $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']= $files['uploadfile']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['uploadfile']['type']= $files['uploadfile']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']= $files['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['uploadfile']['error']= $files['uploadfile']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['uploadfile']['size']= $files['uploadfile']['size'][$i];
    $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());//function defination below
    $this->upload->do_upload('uploadfile');
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    $name_array[] = $upload_data['file_name'];
    $fileName = $upload_data['file_name'];
    $images[] = $fileName;
}
$fileName = $images;
```

`$_FILE` it is an associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the POST method.for the further look this [helper link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

it's an automatic variable available within all scopes of the script

```
function set_upload_options()
{ 
// upload an image options
     $config = array();
     $config['upload_path'] = LARGEPATH; //give the path to upload the image in folder
     $config['remove_spaces']=TRUE;
     $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; // for encrypting the name
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
     $config['max_size'] = '78000';
     $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
     return $config;
}
```

Some basic tip:
An input element must have `multiple=" multiple"` or just multiple.Load `upload` Library.

`$this->upload->do_upload()` will upload the file selected in the given field name to the destination folder.

`$this->upload->data()` returns an array of data related to the uploaded file like the file name, path, size etc.